# Why isn't my NodeJS Web Server Fetching Files from my Directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side, serverside-javascript

I created a `BasicWebServer.js` file which lives in the folder `portfolio-website` and this folder has the following files: `index.htm`, `BasicWebServer.js`, `css/style.css`.

The code I put in the BasicWebServer.js file is as following:

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    host = '127.0.0.1',
    port = '9000';

var mimes = {
    ".htm" : "text/html",
    ".css" : "text/css",
    ".js" : "text/javascript",
    ".gif" : "image/gif",
    ".jpg" : "image/jpeg",
    ".png" : "image/png"
}

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    var filepath = (req.url === '/') ? ('./index.htm') : ('.' + req.url);
    var contentType = mimes[path.extname(filepath)];
    // Check to see if the file exists
    fs.exists(filepath, function(file_exists){
        if(file_exists){
            // Read and Serve
            fs.readFile(filepath, function(error, content){
                if(error){
                    res.writeHead(500);
                    res.end();
                } else{
                    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type' : contentType});
                    res.end(content, 'utf-8');
                }
            })
        } else {
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end("Sorry we could not find the file you requested!");
        }
    })
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type' : 'text/html'});
    res.end('<h1>Hello World!</h1>');
}).listen(port, host, function(){
    console.log('Server Running on http://' + host + ':' + port);
});
```

**UPDATE 1**
Part 1)

I removed the two lines:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'content-type' : 'text/html'});
res.end('<h1>Hello World!</h1>');
```

and when I refresh the page, I get:

`Sorry we could not find the file you requested!`

Part 2)
I have also tried piping it by doing this:

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    host = '127.0.0.1',
    port = '9000';

var mimes = {
    ".htm" : "text/html",
    ".css" : "text/css",
    ".js" : "text/javascript",
    ".gif" : "image/gif",
    ".jpg" : "image/jpeg",
    ".png" : "image/png"
}

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var filepath = (req.url === '/') ? ('./index.htm') : ('.' + req.url);
    var contentType = mimes[path.extname(filepath)];
    // Check to see if the file exists
    fs.exists(filepath, function(file_exists){
//        if(file_exists){
//            // Read and Serve
//            fs.readFile(filepath, function(error, content){
//                if(error){
//                    res.writeHead(500);
//                    res.end();
//                } else{
//                    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type' : contentType});
//                    res.end(content, 'utf-8');
//                }
//            })
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : contentType});
            var streamFile = fs.createReadStream(filepath).pipe(res);

            streamFile.on('error', function() {
                res.writeHead(500);
                res.end();
            })
        } else {
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end("Sorry we could not find the file you requested!");
        }
    })
}).listen(port, host, function(){
    console.log('Server Running on http://' + host + ':' + port);
});
```

This gives the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token else
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Comment: FWIW (among the other existing solutions) you can use [`fs.createReadStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) and then `pipe` it.

Answer (score 3):

These two lines:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'content-type' : 'text/html'});
res.end('<h1>Hello World!</h1>');
```

Are getting executed every time and they get executed before your code has a chance to read the file.  Remember, that `fs.exists()` and `fs.readFile()` are async so their response comes after the rest of your code executes.

If I remove those two lines, your code does start to work so basically you were finishing the response with those two lines before your other code had a chance to actually read the file and send it.

---

FYI, it is considered a bit of an anti-pattern to use `fs.exists()` the way you are using it.  You can just use `fs.readFile()` and handle the error appropriately if the file is not found.  Besides not having concurrency issues, this is also one less file operation.

Answer (score 0):

For sake of education, here is a working version of your example that does not use either `fs.exists` nor `fs.readFile`. Instead it uses `fs.createReadStream` and `.pipe` and `.on('error'`

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    host = '127.0.0.1',
    port = '9000';

var mimes = {
    ".htm": "text/html",
    ".css": "text/css",
    ".js": "text/javascript",
    ".gif": "image/gif",
    ".jpg": "image/jpeg",
    ".png": "image/png"
}

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var filepath = (req.url === '/') ? ('./index.htm') : ('.' + req.url);
    var contentType = mimes[path.extname(filepath)];

    var file = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': contentType
    });
    file.pipe(res);
    file.on('error', function(err) {
        if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end("Sorry we could not find the file you requested!");
        } else {
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end();
        }
    });

}).listen(port, host, function() {
    console.log('Server Running on http://' + host + ':' + port);
    console.log('Serving files from ' + process.cwd());
});
```

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for your input. I tried the code but I get the following error:
`Sorry we could not find the file you requested!`

Is there something I'm missing in my folder? :S

Comment: It shows the 404 message as you requested `http://127.0.0.1:9000/` and `./index.htm` doesn't exist. Request a path that does exist.

Comment: [link](http://i62.tinypic.com/2jd465t.jpg) I think I'm requesting the correct path?

Comment: Use the new code and check that it is serving files from that directory.

Comment: Thanks! It's working, although I had to move my index.htm and css folder to the Desktop, since after running your code, the terminal returned:

`Server Running on http://127.0.0.1:9000
Serving files from `/Users/mahtabalam/Desktop`

Even though the `BasicWebServer.js` is inside `/Users/mahtabalam/Desktop/ma.com-website`, I had to transfer index.htm and css folder out of the `ma.com-website` folder and place them in Desktop. How do I make it so that index.htm is in the same location as the `BasicWebServer.js` location?

Thanks again for all of your help :)

Comment: Add this line after `var filepath`: `filepath = path.join(__dirname, filepath);`.  It makes the path names relative to the directory that contains the script rather than the current working directory. And replace `process.cwd()` with `__dirname`.